# array_rand как выбрать несколько случайных значений из массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Друзья, у меня возник затык, есть массив вида:

```
$array = array(
    1 => rand(1,10),
    2 => rand(1,20),
    3 => rand(1,30)
);
```

Как из такого массива вытащить несколько случайных ключей и значений?

Comment: `echo $array[array_rand($array)];`

Comment: мне нужно НЕСКОЛЬКО

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/549e394a914c356f3c7675f9fd7e57c0f81ffc2e

Comment: Вы не поняли мне нужно чтобы выдало несколько ключей и их значений, то есть примерно так: 1 => 8, 3=> 22.

Comment: В чем проблема вывести циклом?

Comment: у вас все прекрасно, но в том то и дело что мне нужно не только ключ или значение, а миеенно и ключ (он по сути у меня будет айдишкой в таблице) и значение, так как на это значение я буду увеличивать количество в таблице

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Совсем тупанул, можно и с `array_rand`, добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = [
    1 => rand(1,10),
    2 => rand(1,20),
    3 => rand(1,30)
];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i)
    echo $array[array_rand($array)] . PHP_EOL;
```

Или для вывода случайных ключей:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); ++$i)
    echo $keys[array_rand($keys)] . PHP_EOL;
```

Думаю то, что вам нужно:

```
$array = [
    'key1' => 'test1',
    'key2' => 'test2',
    'key3' => 'test3'
];

$keys = array_keys($array);
$val = array_values($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i)
{   
    $rand = rand(0, count($array) - 1);
    echo $keys[$rand].' => '.$val[$rand] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

С использованием `array_rand`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i) {
    $key = array_rand($array);
    echo $key.' => '.$array[$key] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: последний вариант вообще великолепен! спасибо!